# Scrollbars disappearing in IE7

Tags: javascript, css

I can't for the life of me seem to nail down this issue.
It may be a CSS or JS issue.

Please see at https://healthplans.providence.org/Pages/default.aspx

PS. Please don't close this question..  I think it would be beneficial to the community, because this helps troubleshoot a missing scrollbar in IE7.

Comment: It's getting downvoted because people don't want to debug your site for you, and would rather you ask a specific technical question.

Comment: Please add some more specif details to your question so it can be answerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe IE7 simply honors your `body`'s `overflow: hidden;` in the page, despite of all your (other) attempts to override it elsewhere. Try removing that line and see if it helps (it's on line 54 in default.aspx).

Comment: My first thought too, but `document.body.currentStyle.overflow` returns `visible`